# Mysql not started Fedora Core 15

Tags: fedora, mysql

Very dump question. I am very new to Linux . I have installed `mysql` from http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ using the command `yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql mysql-server`. It shows successfull installation. But when I tried to start mysql service `cd /etc/init.d/mysqld start`, it shows `bash: cd: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory`. Please help me. Thanks in advance

EDIT :
I tried running `mysqladmin -u root -p status` produces the following :
`Uptime: 107  Threads: 1  Questions: 2  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 33  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.018` But `localhost/phpmyadmin` shows `404` error

Answer (score 1):

try to `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` without `cd`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

> /etc/init.d/mysqld start

or

> service mysqld start

Comment: `service mysqld start` outputs `Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start mysqld.service`. But when I tried `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` it shows 404 error.

Comment: @suraj-hazarika So, maybe try following commands: **systemctl enable mysqld.service; systemctl start mysqld.service**

Comment: The 404 error is because you don't have any webserver running, in your question you are talking about MySQL. Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: But other normal `php` files are running. So I think Apache is running

Comment: Does phpmyadmin instalation directory exist or it is linked in DocumentRoot of your http daemon?

Comment: ! I dont know . How to check it. Please excuse I am very new to Linux

Comment: @SurajHazarika Default DocumentRoot directory for Apache in Fedora is __/var/www/html__. Moreover, you can check actual value for DocumentRoot parameter in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf